# using a websocket connection destroys php session on refresh

Tags: php, jquery, session, phpwebsocket

I have build up a chat system based on a websocket connection I created using php and jquery.

I also created a simple login. When someone logs in successfully i store this in `$_SESSION` which is checked every time a user opens up the main chat page:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
} //here follows the code for the websocket connection
```

Everything works fine with my login and logout functions and the user is definitely stored in `$_SESSION['user']` because i work with this value in the same file.

So why do i have to log in again every time i refresh the page? Refreshing does not destroy the `$_SESSION` values. Is it because of the websocket connection? 
Does disconnecting from the websocket destroy the `$_SESSION` values?

EDIT:
[I might have found an explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ratchet-php/ekq5Z9Hxz24)

> 1) I don't think so. When the connection is made it does a one time
>   fetch of the session data that is kept in memory for the duration of
>   the WebSocket connection. You can not write back to the storage.
>
> 2) There were two reasons for this: A custom session handler had to be
>   used in order to access the data as the native php session options
>   weren't accessible and the other reason is that because a Ratchet
>   application handles multiple connections global variables are not
>   scoped to one user so $_SESSION is un-usable; Symfony offered both an
>   OO Session API and multiple storage methods.
>   Blockquote

So what can I do to solve my problem? Shall I give Symfony a try?

Last Edit: Very often it's simple in the end.. A misconfigured Logout-Button caused the problem because the session_destroy() method was executed on every reload.
So everything works as expected and hopefully I haven't confused anybody out there.

Comment: have you tried it without websocket?

Comment: yes, there are several pages before this one where the values aren't destroyed.
and the link referring to this page also works and keeps the session value. Only reloading the page with the websocket destroys them.
So it works when i don't use the php websocket